# how to put form text exactly in front of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to put 'email me' & 'call me' text exactly in front radio button. In code it comes under radio button. Can anybody suggest me how to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
$('#emailbtn').on('click',function(){


    if($('#callbtn').prop('checked'))
       {
       $('#callbtn').prop('checked','');       
       }
});


$('#callbtn').on('click',function(){


    if($('#emailbtn').prop('checked'))
       {
       $('#emailbtn').prop('checked','');       
       }
});
</script>
</head>
```

html code is

```
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">
    <input type="radio" value="email" name="select" id="emailbtn" onclick="showemail()" />
Email me :<span id="emailhide" style="display:none"><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email_id" placeholder="*************" /><input type="submit" name="email" value="email" id="emailbtn" style="font-size:16px;" onclick="return validation1()" /></span>
<span id="emailid"></span>
</form>
<form name="form2" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">   
    <input type="radio" value="call" name="select" id="callbtn" onclick="showphn()" />
Call Me :<span id="phonehide" style="display:none"><input type="text" size="50" name="phn" id="call" placeholder="*************" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="call" id="callbtn" onclick="return validation2()" /></span>
<span id="phoneno"></span>
</form>
<input type="radio" value="chat" name="select" id="chatbtn" onclick="showchat()" />
Chat with me<span id="chathide"><a href="valency-networks-chat.html"><input style="display:none" type="submit" name="chat" id="chat" value="Go"/></a></span>
```

Comment: You could use a table for that i guess

Comment: i already used table but no use.

Comment: That is probably becasue you put the text in a `form` tag. There might be a possibility that that's the reason why the browser renders the text on a different line

Comment: Perhaps something like `<label>Email me:<input type="radio" name="select" /></label>` plus do you need multiple `<form>` elements?

Comment: Try adding the radio buttons **IN** the `<form>` tags?

Comment: @ ckuijjer  yes i need maultiple forms

Comment: @ SuperDJ you are right, it comes because i put text in form tag. But as the requirement, i need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){$('#emailbtn').on('click',function(){
 

    if($('#callbtn').prop('checked'))
       {
       $('#callbtn').prop('checked','');       
       }
});


$('#callbtn').on('click',function(){


    if($('#emailbtn').prop('checked'))
       {
       $('#emailbtn').prop('checked','');       
       }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">
    <input type="radio" value="email" name="select" id="emailbtn" onclick="showemail()" />
Email me :<span id="emailhide" style="display:none"><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email_id" placeholder="*************" /><input type="submit" name="email" value="email" id="emailbtn" style="font-size:16px;" onclick="return validation1()" /></span>
<span id="emailid"></span></form>

<form name="form2" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">   
    <input type="radio" value="call" name="select" id="callbtn" onclick="showphn()" />
Call Me :<span id="phonehide" style="display:none"><input type="text" size="50" name="phn" id="call" placeholder="*************" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="call" id="callbtn" onclick="return validation2()" /></span>
<span id="phoneno"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: hey Dhaval, it's not working in my code, as FIDDLE says if u click on 1st radio and then second. it checked both radio button.

Comment: yes Dhaval you are right, but at my place, it's not working, i copied code exactly as you wrote but still not working, choose both radio button. Just FYI, i'l update my code, tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: put this at top of the page <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hey Dhaval while updating code in snippet, it works fine, but actually when going to run through WAMP server, it's not working.

Comment: I checked it that was'nt issue you have some other issue

Comment: Hey Thanks Dhaval, it's working.  It's working if i put script before </BODY>, then itself it work fine.  BDW thanx lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the radio buttons in the forms: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jq5g9o58/)**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">
    <input type="radio" value="email" name="select" id="emailbtn" onclick="showemail()" />Email me :<span id="emailhide" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email_id" placeholder="*************" />
    <input type="submit" name="email" value="email" id="emailbtn" style="font-size:16px;" onclick="return validation1()" />
    <span id="emailid"></span>
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post" style="padding-left:8%;">
    <input type="radio" value="call" name="select" id="callbtn" onclick="showphn()" />Call Me :<span id="phonehide" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="phn" id="call" placeholder="*************" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="call" id="callbtn" onclick="return validation2()" />
    <span id="phoneno"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: hey aditya, it's not working in my code too, as FIDDLE says if u click on 1st radio and then second. it checked both radio button.

Comment: Mangesh both radio option are checked at same time in FIDDLE.

Comment: Cool. Mean while read this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp *Basic stuff*

Comment: You have given two different forms. That is why.

Comment: Hey MAngesh i got your point, but in my code i need to check radio button manually not by default. can you please tell me hoe i do it.

Comment: Aditya from that both forms, need to send mail, so i need these two forms and from both button whichever i choose, it gives textbox for further process.

Comment: Since the radio buttons are different forms then they will be selected separately. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Aditya but as requirements, need to doe the same as i stated.